# Issue with displaying list items css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a list item which has these elements :

- First item
- Another list item
- Sand, Gravel, Clay, and Ceramic and Refractory Minerals Mining and Quarrying materials

And I want them to look they do look above in this question all in one line or if the item gets too big break it nicely like this :

- Sand, Gravel, Clay, and Ceramic and Refractory Minerals Mining and Quarrying materials big name which is aligning nicely

But instead my items look like this(screen shot) :

[image]

As you can see it doesn't look good. This is my html structure :

```
<ul class="something">
  <li>
     <div style="width:auto; display:inline-block;">
       <span>This is where super long text goes text goes</span>
     </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

`ul and li` don't have any style on them just those inherited from bootstrap css.

Which css do I use so that my list from the screen shot looks like the first one in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul class="something">
  <li>
       This is where super long text goes text goes
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Joris, I can't do that as we're using plugin which puts the div around my span element

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8hfgR/ - or is it also impossible to change the inline styles?

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
ul.something li div {vertical-align: top}
```

and it should work as you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want horizontal lists, use the following CSS:

`li{display:inline;}`

Answer (score 0):

Put this on your stylesheet:

```
.something li div{display:inline;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: In your code **display:inline-block** is breaking the list. So try after removing that

```
<ul >
  <li><div style="width:auto; "><span>First item</span></div></li>
  <li><div style="width:auto;"><span>Another list item</span></div></li>
 <li><div style="width:auto;"><span>Sand, Gravel, Clay, and Ceramic and Refractory Minerals Mining and Quarrying materials</span></div></li>
</ul>
```